# Manipulate 2D symbolic parametric curves in Python

Tags: python, geometry, symbolic-math

I am trying to compute intersections, distances and derivatives on 2D symbolic parametric curves (that is a curve defined on the plan by a function) but I can't find any Python module that seems to do the job.

So far I have only found libraries that deal with plotting or do numerical approximation so I thought I could implement it myself as a light overlay on top of a symbolic mathematics library.

I start experimenting with [SymPy](http://sympy.org/en/index.html) but I can wrap my head around it: it doesn't seems to be able to return intervals even in finite number (for instance solve(x = x) fails !) and only a small numbers of solutions is some simple cases.

What tool could be suitable for the task ?

Answer (score 0):

I guess that parametric functions relate to the advanced topics of mathematical analysis, and I haven't seen any libraries yet that could match your demands. However you could try to look through the docs of the [Sage](http://www.math.ucla.edu/~jimc/mathnet_d/sage/reference/sage/plot/plot3d/parametric_plot3d.html) project...

Comment: Unfortunately it seems this part of sage is mostly for plotting and graphical representation but not really for manipulation or computing. It might be possible to use some other part of sage (at it can apparently be invoked quite easily in Python) but I didn't really find how until now.

Answer (score 0):

It would help if you give an example of two curves that you want to define. `solve` is up to the task for finding intersections of all quadratic curves (it will actually solve quartics and some quintics, too).

When you say "distance" what do you mean - arc length sort of distance or distance from a point to the curve?

As for tangents, that is easily handled with `idiff` (see its docstring for examples with `help(idiff)`.

Comment: Mostly it is going to be Bezier curves, lines and elliptical arcs in orthonormal frame. So it's gonna be polynomials of degree less than 4 and simple expression using sin and cos : x(t) = a + b cos(u t) + c sin(v t) and y(t) = a' + b' cos(u' t) + c' sin(v' t) for elliptical arcs  and x(t) = a + b t + c t^2 + d t^3 and y(t) = a' + b' t + c' t^2 + d' t^3 for Bezier curves . It's all pretty simple so I could compute the intersections and tangents myself. I also want to do rotations translations and scalings which won't be as free If I have to do them by hand ...

Comment: But for distance I want the minimal euclidean distance between any two points one on each curve, and I'd rather not compute that.

I gave a look at idiff and that'd be exactly what I was looking for for the derivatives.

My first guess too was that sympy and solve were usuable but I did some quick stupid tests, like x-x = 0, cos(x)=1/2 or cos(100-t)-sin(100+t) = 0, and many failed or showed only partial solutions. Maybe I'm missing some option to give to solve or some formatting ?